# Xpath not getting content

Tags: html, xml, xpath, google-sheets

I've tried looking through a bunch of answers already related to this, but I'm very unfamiliar with xpath and I'm a bit stuck.

I'm trying to just grab some information from a website, but I keep getting "imported content is empty" when i try to use importxml in excel.

Here's an example of the page I'm trying to read from (it's a college football simulator for running games. This call is Alabama vs Oklahoma using the 2019 teams):
http://www.ncaagamesim.com/FB_GameSimulator.asp?HomeTeam=Alabama&HomeYear=2019&AwayTeam=Oklahoma&AwayYear=2019&hs=1&hSchedule=0

I'm trying to grab the two teams' scores from the above link.
The first team's score's xpath is supposedly `/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/center/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]`
but I keep getting an empty response.

I'm trying to use importxml in google sheets to get the data.

This returns quite a bit, but it doesn't appear to have the info I need.  `=importxml("http://www.ncaagamesim.com/FB_GameSimulator.asp?HomeTeam=Alabama&HomeYear=2019&AwayTeam=Oklahoma&AwayYear=2019&hs=1&hSchedule=0", "//div[contains(@class,gs_score)]")`

If I quote the gs_score, it doesn't return anything.

Would appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

**Edit:** The xpath fails with /html/body/div[3]. If I change this to div[2], it returns some of the page data, but not the part I'm looking for.

According to an article I found -

> Unfortunately, ImportXML doesn’t load JavaScript, so you won’t be able
>   to use this function if the content of the document is generated by
>   JavaScript (jQuery, etc.)

Not sure if this is relevant...

**Edit 2:**

[image: Value I want to get is 14]

I noticed the values I need are in an html table, so I tried using this

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.ncaagamesim.com/FB_GameSimulator.asp?HomeTeam=Alabama&HomeYear=2019&AwayTeam=Oklahoma&AwayYear=2019&hs=1&hSchedule=0", "table",1)
```

I'm still getting no content, no matter what table number I put in that formula.

If I copy the selector in the inspector, we get:

```
body > div.container > div > div > div.container > div > div.col-lg-9 > center > div:nth-child(3) > div.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.gs_score.gs_borderright.rightalign > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)
```

Which seems to be the same as the xpath.

Answer (score -1):

Part of the answer: 'gs_score' needs to be in quotes - it's a string literal, not an element name. As an element name, it selects nothing, and everything contains nothing, so the predicate is always true.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but it now returns "imported content is empty"

. 
Double quotes breaks the formula, so I tried using single quotes.

    "//div[contains(@class,'gs_score')]"